# How do I convert/display a datatype in Bytes or something else? Like a debugger does in MemoryViewer

Tags: c++, debugging, types, type-conversion

Okay so I cant find a good way to ask this question so google is not helping me (my english sucks).

And pls dont come with simple char to hex converter answers.

If there is any link to the same question would also help.

I have the following example.

```
template <typename t>
std::string ByteHexDisplay(t variable) {

  return "";
}


int main()
{
    char value_char = 'A';
    int value_int = 5453;
    char question1[] = "What is your name? ";  


    ByteHexDisplay(value_char);     //returns  41 #picture1

    ByteHexDisplay(value_int);      //returns 4d 15 00 00 #picture2

    ByteHexDisplay(question1);      //returns 57 68 61 74 20 69 73 20 79 6f 75 72 20 6e 61 6d 65 3f 20 00 #picture3



}
```

I want the representive byte in memory printed,like a debugger does, is there any good way?

Pictures of Memory Dump Debugger

[image: value_char]

[image: value_int]

[image: question1]

Comment: `auto* bytes = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&value);` Which can be dereferenced and printed in whatever format you want. `printf,cout` can also print hex values.

Answer (score 0):

You can print a value as a hexadecimal number with `std::cout` by using `std::hex`:

```
std::cout << std::hex << 3735928559 << std::endl;
```

In order to view an entire item byte-by-byte, delimited with spaces, you can mask and shift. If `T` is the type (or generic) of `var`, this will work:

```
std::size_t len = sizeof T * 8;
while(len > 0)
{
    std::cout << std::hex << (var & 0xFF) << " ";
    var >>= 8;
    len -= 8;
}
```

This assumes a byte is 8 bits on your system, but in 99% of cases that's a pretty safe assumption to make.

Comment: I mean this works for Integral types but what about floating point types or strings where i cant bit shift and mask?